# Issue with path using twig templates

Tags: path, twig

I'm currently resuming an existing project and I'm facing path issues with a twig (the project use no framework for twig templates). I'm trying to run this project locally with wampserver. I defined my new base-path so that wamp can run it but it can't redirect me correctly when I'm using forms for example. It can't also find paths to images.

For example, I can try to connect using the URL:

```
localhost/autres/admin_LP/admin
```

but when I submit I'm redirected to:

```
localhost/admin/dashboard
```

instead of:

```
localhost/autres/admin_LP/admin/dashboard
```

In other terms, the part "/autres/admin_LP" is missing.
It's the same issue for images, the path is wrong:
[incorrect path for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GS0ne.png)

The image path should be:

```
localhost/autres/admin_LP/Web/template/View/Easylife.png
```

instead of:

```
localhost/Web/template/View/Easylife.png
```

Apparently, I correctly modified the .htaccess since I'm directed towards the connection page. But since the project uses twig templates, I think I missed some twig configuration so that it can find the right path.
I'm a rookie with twig templates so if you have any clue about how I can properly run my project locally, I'm more than interested!

Comment: I think you should explain if you're using a framework.